# How to solve "ResourceMap Not Found" exception error

Tags: c#, resx, microsoft-store

I am trying my best to have my app show up in the MS store under the "Languages supported in packages" section. I can get it to show the default language (English), no problem, but the MS Store simply refuses to list any other language. I have tried everything from here...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/manage-language-and-region

This is what my store configuration shows..

[image]

I have a bunch of language localised pictures in various resx files and even though the correct language folders are created in the bin directory and by changing the CultureCode, the correct language pictures are used, I have no luck with the Store.

Thinking that resx files are simply not compatable, I am now trying to setup some strings in resw files, but cannot get it to work. I figure I am missing something simple, but just cannot see it and that is where I need help.

I have created a short test project following the instructions at...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest

The first problem was that I could not find where to add the resw files from as the project would only allow for the addition of resx files. Eventually I discovered that I could get them by adding a file from the Installer package and then cut/paste to the project.

So I could use the Windows.Application.Resources methods, I set the Target OS thus...

[image]

The next issue was the instructions state...

[image]

Ok, I got that error, but now what!!

Hunting around the web I found a solution. You simply replace

```
ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
```

with

```
ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();
```

Now I am getting the Exception "ResourceMap Not Found". More research and apparently to resolve this, you simple add the resource path as a parameter. Still getting the error though...

[image]

Considering what I have tried above my direct question is:

**How do I make the "ResourceMap Not Found" error go away?**

Any tips on getting the MS Store listings to show multiple languages also appreciated!